# Skip hitting enter at the boot option and directly boot the system

Tags: grub2, 9.10

I have recently installed ubuntu 9.10 desktop edition. I had to do manual shutdown pressing the power & reset button 2-3 times. So when ever I power on the system, the system waits at the boot menu till I hit enter. I think there may be some tricks so that I can skip the boot option and directly boot the system without needing to hit enter at the boot option?. Any help...

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do this. Though I would imagine that shutting down your system correctly would not trigger this again. Try hitting CTRL+ALT+T and at the console type "sudo shutown 0" or "sudo reboot" after typing in your admin password it should shutdown correctly.

Comment: Do you mean you need to press enter during GRUB (a menu shoing grub on the title)?

Comment: @joao Pinto: yes, I've to hit enter on the grub options for the system to be booted.

Comment: @Kyle Clarke: I'll try that.

Comment: you should just need to use startup manager or edit grub to boot automatically...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install startup manager by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

Then run startupmanager, and change the timeout to 0. This should work. HOWEVER!!! BE WARNED THAT THIS CAN MAKE IT HARD TO RECOVER FROM A DISASTER!!! The best way is to press enter before you boot, so then you can rescue your system easier, but you lose some convenience.

Comment: +1 - For StartUpManager. More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager).